# How to replace the company name in the template headers in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode-template

When Xcode creates a new file, there's always something like this in the header:

```
//  Copyright 2009 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
```

How can I change that?

Comment: Just a note for visitors: In Xcode 4 company name is set at project level, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770126/how-can-i-change-the-copyright-template-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 10):

You can change it in Xcode project File. This is my image for tutorial.
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Xcode will try to pull this information from your entry in the system address book - if you can't modify it there, try using this command to override:

`defaults write com.apple.xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions '{ ORGANIZATIONNAME = "ORGNAME";}'`

Answer (score 8):

As a follow-up to the answer above, for documentation of that and many other preferences see [the Xcode defaults reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005535-CH3-SW6)

Answer (score 1):

As of xcode 3, it will use the "company" field from your Address Book card if the "PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions" key is missing from com.apple.Xcode.plist.

Answer (score 0):

defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions ' { "ORGANIZATIONNAME" = "javacom"; } '

Entered in Terminal.