# iphone default SDK preferences

Tags: iphone

I Keep building projects and then have to do a find and replace for the automatically commented out copy right information in each page. It gets my name right but then it's puts my day job in as the company at the top of each page. It's annoying and also a point where my day job employer could claim rights to my off time work. How do I change this? I think it get's it from my registration information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was already answered: [How to replace the company name in the template headers in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132855/how-to-replace-the-company-name-in-the-template-headers-in-xcode).