# How can I change the company name in the copyright template in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode-template, copyright-display

Does anyone know how to change copyright in the templates for Xcode? That is, at the top of a new file it writes:

```
//  Copyright 2011 {Company Name}. All rights reserved.
```

In previous Xcode versions you could change it by running the following command in the terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions '{"ORGANIZATIONNAME" = “{Company Name}";}’
```

In Xcode 4.0 this method no longer works.

Comment: Does it work if you set the company field for your own entry in Address Book?

Comment: I tried changing that, and gave the computer a reset to no success.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Xcode 4 (and above) stores this on a per-project basis.

If you select the project in the Project Navigator (Cmd-1) and open the File Inspector (Cmd-Opt-1), you'll see a field for "Organization" under "Project Document".

Answer (score 78):

You can change the copyright template in Xcode here:

Project Navigator -> File Inspector -> "Organization".

[image]

Comment: This actually helped me figure out where the Organization name was stored in my project. Thanks for that! (worked on XCode 12.2)

Answer (score 30):

`__MyCompanyName__` being ugly (or if you aren't coding for the company set up in your profile), let's change it.

1. Click on your project root in the `Project Navigator` on the left
2. Enable your *Utilities* view on the right while the project root is highlighted
3. Select the `File Inspector`, while the Identity displays your `Project Name`.
4. Under `Project Document` is a text field called *Organization*. That's the proper place to set the value you want.

Answer (score 10):

You can find the template files in `/Developer/Library/XCode/Templates/`

Comment: Thanks Macmade. For any one looking todo this I have replaced “___ORGANIZATIONNAME___" in each of the files with what I want the copyright to be.

Comment: Sadly, Apple has deleted the /Developer folder for Lion/Mountain Lion. This answer doesn't work any more :(

Comment: The same folder hierarchy can now be found inside the xCode application bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to the Address Book application on your Mac and change the company name that is listed under your own address card.